# Render partial page on popup dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am trying to load a partial view onto a popup dialog box.

I have created the code for the dialog box which works. i would like to know how i would be able to load this partial view onto the dialog box though a link click all the code is provided below about the link, `java script and popup dialog box`.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="mediaContainer" class="jqmDialog" style= "width:750px; left:23%; top:18%; height:525px; ">
   <div class="jqmnTitle jqDrag">
    <h1>Subscriptions</h1>    
    </div>
    <img class="jqmClose" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; right: 2px; top: 2px;" onclick="closeDialog();" src="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images/close.gif")" 
            alt="Close" height="20px" width="20px" />

      <center>  
        <div id="divpart"></div>

       </center>
 </div>
```

**JAVA script:**

```
   function renderPart(element, templateId) {
       makeDialogBox();
jQuery.get(FBUrl, { id: templateId }, function (data) {
               // alert(data);
               $("divpart").append(data);
       });

   }
```

**Hyper Link:**

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline;" class = "lnkShowMarketRates" onclick="renderPart(this.id, @item.id);">Subscriptions</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the XMLHttpRequest to your URL of the partial view using native javascript or jquery and append the output to one of the div inside the modal dialog box. I am using jquery

```
          function renderPart(element, templateId){
           $.ajax({
             url : '',
             type : 'GET',
             succsess : function(response)
             {  $("#divIDinsideModalBox").html(response); makeDialogBox();   }
           });
         }
```

Comment: can u give me an example please

Comment: @user2306809 updated my code with , wrap the ajax call inside the function and call the function on the click of the link

Comment: I realsied that i forgot that

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.get("InsertURLHere", { id: templateId }, function (data) {
               // alert(data);
               $("divpart").append(data);
       });
```